# Getting error while creating subtitles to videos in twitter

Tags: php, laravel, twitter

i been trying to add subtitles to videos  subtitle file is uploading and got medaid and then i called `media/subtitles/create` endpoint with params

```
{
  "media_id":"692797692624265216",
  "media_category":"TweetVideo",
  "subtitle_info": {
    "subtitles": [
      "media_id":"105195515189863968",
      "language_code":"EN", //The language code should be a BCP47 code (e.g. 'en", "sp"),
      "display_name":"English"
    ]
  }
}
```

but its returning `undefined index media_type` then i passed media_type then it returned `undefined index media`, that also i passed then i got `undefined media_string_id` after passing that value i got `Undefined property: stdClass::$media_id_string’`, in document these values are not specified for subtitle creation
any thought on these please share your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed this issue with below codes

```
$media_type = mime_content_type($local_file_path);
$subtitleMediaDetails = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' =>$local_file_path, 'media_type' =>$media_type, 'media_category'=> 'Subtitles'],true);
```

```
 $subtitleMedaiId = $subtitleMediaDetails->media_id;           
 if($subtitleMedaiId) {
    $json = '{
       "media_id":"'.$media->media_id.'", // uploaded video id 
       "media_category":"TweetVideo",
       "subtitle_info": {
          "subtitles": [
              {
                  "media_id":"'.$subtitleMedaiId.'", //uploaded subtitle video id
                  "language_code":"EN",
                  "display_name":"English"
              }
           ]
          }
        }';
    $metadata_payload = json_decode($json, true);
    $connection->setTimeouts(60, 60);
    $createdSubritleResponse = $connection->post('media/subtitles/create', $metadata_payload, true); 
}
```

Comment: Indent the code properly. It's very hard to read as it is.